# Timeout occurred while executing CnosDB tenant creation

Tags: cnosdb

SQL:

```
create tenant if not exists 'Tenant11SubOrg12' with _limiter= '{\"object_config\": {\"max_users_number\": 10,\"max_databases\": 3,\"max_retention_time\": 30},\"request_config\": {\"data_in\": {\"remote_bucket\": {\"max\": 5242880,\"initial\": 0,\"refill\": 5242880,\"interval\": 300000},\"local_bucket\": {\"max\": 5242880,\"initial\": 300000}},\"data_out\": {\"remote_bucket\": {\"max\":314572800,\"initial\": 0,\"refill\": 314572800,\"interval\": 300000},\"local_bucket\": {\"max\": 314572800,\"initial\": 300000}},\"queries\": {\"remote_bucket\": {\"max\": 100,\"initial\": 0,\"refill\": 100,\"interval\": 300000},\"local_bucket\": {\"max\": 100,\"initial\": 0}},\"writes\": {\"remote_bucket\": {\"max\": 300,\"initial\": 0,\"refill\": 300,\"interval\": 300000},\"local_bucket\": {\"max\": 300,\"initial\": 0}}}}';
```

Log:

```
[2023/08/24 07:15:06.602 +00:00] [INFO] [tenant.go:50] [message] [msg="Post \"http://tskv-0.tskv:21001/api/v1/sql\": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"]
[2023/08/24 07:15:07.743 +00:00] [INFO] [tenant.go:50] [message] [msg="Post \"http://tskv-0.tskv:21001/api/v1/sql\": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"]
```

How can this problem be resolved?